# New installation freezes at loading initramfs

Tags: initramfs, freeze

Recently I got [Acer Aspire ES 14](http://www.acer.com/datasheets/2016/4876/ES1-431/NX.G6CEC.001.html) into my hands and wanted to install Lubuntu on it. I dissabled UEFI, system was successfully installed but it freezes after reboot.

I tried to boot in recovery mode and since there are few echo debugging messages I found it get stuck at loading initrd (after message "Loading initial ramdisk").

I have no idea how to debug it to find out what's the problem. I tried to boot with "nosplash debug" kernel parameters and adding "nomodeset" at the end, but no combination works.

The problem might be the laptop's only storage is 32gb eMMC. Even when I add modules mmc_core, mmc_block, sdhci, sdhci-pci for supporting SD card boot and update-initramfs, it doesn't help.

How do I debug it or what might be the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This modules are usually integrated in the initrd. Did you check the    integrity of the Download of your Iso and your Installations-medium (DVD/USB)?  Hier xenial

```
lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-45-generic | grep mmc
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/card
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/card/mmc_block.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/card/sdio_uart.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/usdhi6rol0.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/wbsd.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/ushc.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/sdricoh_cs.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-pltfm.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/tifm_sd.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/cb710-mmc.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/toshsd.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/vub300.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/mtk-sd.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/via-sdmmc.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-pci.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/sdhci-acpi.ko
lib/modules/4.4.0-45-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/rtsx_usb_sdmmc.ko
```

Modules like mmc_core, mmc_block are not known in Lubuntu.

Comment: I see, though it doesn't boot even without specifying the modules. Just trying Mint, still the same and the integrity is alright.

Comment: integrity of this storage 32gb eMMC too?

Comment: Yes, also without problem... After all trying I installed it again in UEFI and it's finally working.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find solution for legacy boot but solved it by installing system in UEFI.